# Textbox should be disabled unless a certain option in the dropdown box is selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, disabled-input

Here's my JavaScript code: it's not working

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function ShowExpenseReport(Expense_Report_ID) {
        var width = screen.width;  
        var leftpad = (width - 740) / 2;
        var jsoption = "width=740,height=700,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no,left=" + leftpad + ",top=10";

        window.open("Documents/ExpenseReport.aspx?Expense_Report_ID=" + Expense_Report_ID, 'win02', jsoption);
        return false;
    }

    function changetextbox() {
        if (document.getElementById("ddlItem").value == '3') {
            document.getElementById("txtPurpose").disabled = 'true';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("txtPurpose").disabled = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Below is the HTML side:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="innerGridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemPadding"
    ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        Item
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblItem" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Item_Description") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblItemID" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Item_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" Width="140px" runat="server"  onChange="changetextbox()"  CssClass="combobox">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="innerGridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemPadding"
    ItemStyle-Width="260px" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        Purpose
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPurpose" runat="server" Width="240px" Text='<%#Eval("Purpose") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPurpose" runat="server" Width="240px" CssClass="inputbox" Text='<%#Eval("Purpose") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPurpose" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Purpose"
            ControlToValidate="txtPurpose" Display="None" ValidationGroup="NER" SetFocusOnError="True">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vcePurpose" runat="server" TargetControlID="rfvPurpose"
            PopupPosition="BottomRight" WarningIconImageUrl="~/Library/Images/exclamation.png" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I just want to disable the textboxes when the user chooses entertainment from the dropdown which has the value 3 in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is disable/enable a textbox field on the basis of select value. A proper way followed in ASP is as follows, try this:

```
onchange="DisableTextBox();"

<script language=javascript>
    function DisableTextBox() {
        var dropDown = document.getElementById('<%=DropDown.ClientID%>'); 

        if (dropDown.selectedIndex = ValueTocompare) {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtBoxID.ClientID%>').disabled = disabled;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtBoxID.ClientID%>').disabled = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

if this doesn't work out for you, try using this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SurajMindfire/zxvfcvq0/

Comment: Thanks for your response hussain, but unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

1. dropdown is there contain YES and No value(by default yes),
2. there is text  box, when user select YES value from dropdown textbox will enabled but when select No value then textbox get desabled.
3. astric is id for validation of textbox

```js
function EnableDisableInputField(customerNarration) {
  var selectedValue = customerNarration.options[customerNarration.selectedIndex].value;
  var txtOther = document.getElementById("customisedNarration");
  txtOther.disabled = selectedValue == 'N' ? true : false;

  document.getElementById("asterisk").innerHTML = "";

  if (!txtOther.disabled) {
    txtOther.focus();
    document.getElementById("asterisk").innerHTML = "*";
  }
  var checkError = document.getElementById("customisedNarration_box").style = "display: none";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="floatinglabel"><sup class="text-red">*</sup> Customer Narration required</label>
  <div class="selectwrapper">
    <select class="form-control" id="customerNarration" name="customerNarration" onchange="EnableDisableInputField(this)" onfocus="hideerrmsgdelayed('customerNarration')">
      <option value="Y">Yes</option>
      <option value="N">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span class="inputError" id="customerNarrationReq_box"><%=siteValidation.getErrorMessage("customerNarration")%></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="floatinglabel"><sup class="text-red" id="asterisk"></sup> Customised Narration </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customisedNarration" id="customisedNarration" onfocus="hideerrmsgdelayed('customisedNarration')" maxlength="50" />
  <span class="inputError" id="customisedNarration_box"><%=siteValidation.getErrorMessage("customisedNarration")%></span>
</div>
```